# How to write query to get the mentioned results

Tags: sql

[image: Kindly refer this image]

I want to write SQL query to find.

1. create_date (first instance when order created)
2. modified_date (first instance when status is equal to 1)
3. end_date (last instance when status is equal to 3)

I am very new to SQL, and I am finding it difficult to get such results.

Comment: I removed the conflicting DBMS tags. Please add only **one** tag for the database product you are really using.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what RDBMS you're using, but typically you can do something like this with case and min / max:

```
select
    customer_id,
    min(create_date),
    min(case when status = 1 then modified_date end),
    max(case when status = 3 then end_date end)
from
    ...
group by
    customer_id
```